# What is the length of Android serial number (ro.serialno)?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I get the serial no from

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");           
Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class );       
String serialNo = (String) (get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno", ""));
```

But what is the max. length of the `ro.serialno`?

From the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Seems it is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the source code, I would say 103.

The variable name is `PROP_VALUE_MAX`

If you are talking about the lenght of the variable name, then look for `PROP_NAME_MAX` which its length is 31.

[Source.](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/frameworks_base/blobs/1ecf4985903139c6e60ff74f189cc9a700d24412/core/java/android/os/SystemProperties.java)

Answer (score 1):

Rely on the cts suite, the `ro.serialno` should be following this pattern:

```
Pattern SERIAL_NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([0-9A-Za-z]{6,20})$");
```

In `BuildTest.java`, line 159 at time of writing: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/os/src/android/os/cts/BuildTest.java#159

Comment: Found it (line 159 as of writing): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/os/src/android/os/cts/BuildTest.java#159